# Notes not updated in Visio 2010 reverse engineer with SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server, reverse-engineering, visio

I am using ms sql server as the driver to construct a datasource when I do the reverse engineering in the visio 2010. Only tables are imported. E-R diagram generated is fine although only part of tables are automatically added but it's fine. The problem is the notes of tables and specific fields are not "updated" even after manually refersh the data. It just keeps what it was when they are created.

The only way to "update" I find is to delete all components and redo the reverse engineering, which obviously should not be called "refresh".

Anyone encounter this issue before?

PS: the "refresh" button always shows strange "confliction" between visio model and DB. For instance, it may detect changes even when I have not done anything in the DB at all. And there is an "Update databse" radio button (although it is always gray when I test) in the refresh model wizard dialog makes me wonder can it update the changes on the visio model to DB somehow?